# What is Maximum Entropy?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, entropy

Can someone give me a clear and simple definition of Maximum entropy classification? It would be very helpful if someone can provide a clear analogy, as I am struggling to understand.

Answer (score 9):

"Maximum Entropy" is synonymous with "Least Informative". You wouldn't want a classifier that was least informative. It is in reference to how the priors are established. Frankly, "Maximum Entropy Classification" is an example of using buzz words.

For an example of an uninformative prior, consider given a six-sided object. The probability that any given face will appear if the object is tossed is 1/6. This would be your starting prior. It's the least informative. You really wouldn't want to start with anything else or you will bias later calculations. Of course, if you have  knowledge  that one side will appear more often you should incorporate that into your priors.

The Bayes formula is P(H|E) = P(E|H)P(H)/P(D)
where P(H) is the prior for the hypothesis and P(D) is the sum of all possible numerators.

For text classification where a missing word is to be inserted, E is some given document and  H is the given word. IOW, the hypothesis is that H is the word which should be selected and P(H) is the weight given to the word.

Maximum Entropy Text classification means: start with least informative weights (priors) and optimize to find weights that maximize the likelihood of the data, the P(D). Essentially, it's the EM algorithm.

A simple Naive Bayes classifier would assume the prior weights would be proportional to the number of times the word appears in the document. However,this ignore correlations between words.

The so-called *MaxEnt* classifier, takes the correlations into account.

I can't think of a simple example to illustrate this but I can think of some correlations. For example, "the *missing*" in English should give higher weights to nouns but a Naive Bayes classifier might give equal weight to a verb if its relative frequency were the same as a given noun. A MaxEnt classifier considering *missing* would give more weight to nouns because they would be more likely in context.

Comment: Good explanation.

I would add that the MaxEnt principle also has to do with the resulting classifier, it should be the least informative classifier available (alternatively with "maximal entropy") that classifies the data well.

Implicitly, this assure you that your classifier is not overfitting your training data.

Comment: Why do you need D in the Bayes formula? D is E.

Comment: P(D) is a normalizing constant = sum(all possible numerators) as I mentioned. Forces the results, P(H|E), to be in the interval [0,1], I suppose you could say P(E) instead but it would be confusing as E is already used for Evidence.

Comment: Strictly speaking, P(D) is not a probability as all probabilities must have a basis, P(X | E) vs. P(X).

Comment: I would change P(D) to something like Z and just explained it is a sum as well as a normalizing factor. When you introduce a new variable, you make it more confusing for someone who are trying to learn. I skipped that bit in the first skimming because I know exactly what Bayes' rue means. Reading this again feels confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I may also advise [HIDDEN MARKOV AND
MAXIMUM ENTROPY
MODELS](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Ejason/papers/jurafsky+martin.bookdraft07.ch6.pdf) from the Department of Computer Science, Johns Hopkins. Specifically, take a look at chapter 6.6. This book explains the Maximum Entropy on the example of PoS tagging and compare MaxEnt application in MEMM with Hidden Markov Model. There are also explanation what is exactly MaxEnt with math behind.

Answer (score 0):

(Taken from [UNDERSTANDING DEEP LEARNING
GENERALIZATION
BY
MAXIMUM
ENTROPY (Zheng et al., 2017)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.07758.pdf):

(Original Maximum Entropy Model) Supposing the dataset has input X and label
Y, the task is to find a good prediction of Y using X. The prediction Yˆ needs to maximize the
conditional entropy H(Yˆ |X) while preserving the same distribution with data (X, Y ). This is
formulated as:

min −H(Yˆ |X) (1)

s.t. P(X, Y ) = P(X, Yˆ ),
\sum(Yˆ) P(Yˆ |X) = 1

Berger et al., 1996 solves this with lagrange multipliers ωi as an exponential form:

Pω(Yˆ = y|X = x) = 1/Zω(x) exp (\sum(i) ωifi(x, y))